# How to unwrap optional tuple of options to tuple of options in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list of `Person` and want to retrieve a person by its `id`

```
val person = personL.find(_.id.equals(tempId))
```

After that, I want to get as a tuple the first and last element of a list which is an attribute of `Person`.

```
val marks: Option[(Option[String], Option[String])] = person.map { p =>
              val marks = p.school.marks
              (marks.headOption.map(_.midtermMark), marks.lastOption.map(_.finalMark))
}
```

This work's fine but now I want to transform the `Option[(Option[String], Option[String])]` to a simple `(Option[String], Option[String])`. Is it somehow possible to do this on-the-fly by using the previous map?

Comment: What should happen in case the option of tuple is none? Would you want a default value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose:

```
person.map{...}.getOrElse((None, None))
```

`(None, None)` is a default value here in case if your option of tuple is empty

Answer (score 0):

You are, probably, looking for `fold`:

```
personL
 .collectFirst {
    case Person(`tempId`, _, .., school) => school.marks
 }.fold[Option[String], Option[String]](None -> None) { marks => 
    marks.headOption.map(_.midtermMark) -> marks.lastOption.map(_.finalMark) 
 }
```